# How to manually add NDK location android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have RubyMotion installed for developing android apps in native Ruby language. `motion android-setup` downloads android SDK and NDK in ~/.rubymotion-android directory

[image]

Now, I have set up sdk location from to `~/.rubymotion-android/sdk` but how to set ndk location in android studio preferences?

There are no option in preferences to set android ndk location in android studio. By default ndk is downloaded in sdk folder: `sdk/ndk-bundle/`. But here in my case I want to set ndk location to `~/.rubymotion/ndk`

[image]

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: You can use ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable to set NDK location instead

Comment: @jomartigcal I took this random picture from google. But, I am using 1.4 september 2015 built.